# Maven JAR file only includes HTML files, not Scala classes

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, sbt-sonatype

I followed [this guide](https://leonard.io/blog/2017/01/an-in-depth-guide-to-deploying-to-maven-central/) to release a Scala / SBT JAR file in Maven.

I ran the `sbt publishSigned` and `sbt sonatypeRelease` for the spark-fast-tests 0.11.0 release and the JAR file was correctly built.  [See here](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.mrpowers%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spark-fast-tests_2.11%22).  These commands come from the [sbt-sonatype](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype#command-line-usage) plugin.

For some reason, when I did the 0.12.0 release, the Maven JAR file only includes HTML files and images.  For example, the downloaded JAR file contains this file `com/github/mrpowers/spark/fast/tests/DatasetComparer.html`, but doesn't include `DatasetComparer.class`.

The `target/scala-2.11/spark-fast-tests_2.11-2.3.0_0.12.0.jar` file also only includes the HTML files (either `sbt publishSigned` or `sbt sonatypeRelease` must have generated this JAR file).

When I run `sbt package`, the JAR file that's generated includes the Scala classes like `com/github/mrpowers/spark/fast/tests/DatasetComparer.class`, as expected.

spark-fast-tests is an open source project and here is the [build.sbt file](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-fast-tests/blob/master/build.sbt).

How can I include my project classes in the JAR file that's uploaded to Maven?  Any tips / tricks on how to debug this better?

Answer (score 1):

Analysing spark-fast-tests `build.sbt` I would make the following recommendations:

1. Add [`sbt-release`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) to `plugins.sbt` to enable release process customisation:

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz"  % "sbt-release"   % "1.0.8")
   addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt"     % "sbt-sonatype"  % "2.0")
   addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth"       % "sbt-pgp"       % "1.1.0")
   ```
2. Create `version.sbt` at project root and move `version` setting out of `build.sbt`:

   ```
   version in ThisBuild := "0.12.1-SNAPSHOT"
   ```
3. Create `sonatype.sbt` at project root and move the following settings out of `build.sbt`:

   ```
   homepage := Some(url("https://github.com/mrpowers/spark-fast-tests/"))
   scmInfo := Some(
       ScmInfo(
       url("https://github.com/mrpowers/spark-fast-tests/"),
       "git@github.com:mrpowers/spark-fast-tests.git"
       )
   )
   developers := List(
       Developer(
       "mrpowers",
       "Matthew Powers",
       "matthewkevinpowers@gmail.com",
       url("https://github.com/mrpowers/spark-fast-tests/")
       )
   )
   licenses += ("MIT", url("http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"))
   publishMavenStyle := true
   ```
4. Add the following release settings to `build.sbt`:

   ```
   import sbtrelease.ReleaseStateTransformations._

   publishTo := Some(
     if (isSnapshot.value) { Opts.resolver.sonatypeSnapshots }
     else { Opts.resolver.sonatypeReleases }
   )

   releasePublishArtifactsAction := PgpKeys.publishSigned.value
   releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
     checkSnapshotDependencies,
     inquireVersions,
     runClean,
     runTest,
     setReleaseVersion,
     commitReleaseVersion,
     tagRelease,
     publishArtifacts,
     setNextVersion,
     commitNextVersion,
     releaseStepCommand("sonatypeReleaseAll"),
     pushChanges
   )
   ```
5. Release to Maven Central with `sbt release`

For a working example have a look at build configuration of [`sbt-sonatype`](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype/) itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  I followed all your steps and ran the `sbt release` command.  I'll report back and accept your answer when I've confirmed that the Maven JAR file contains the Scala classes (as you know, Maven has quite the lag).

Comment: I did the spark-fast-tests 0.12.1 release with your code and unfortunately the JAR file still only contains HTML, gif, js, png, etc. files.  You can go to Maven, download the jar, and run the `jar tvf spark-fast-tests_2.11-0.12.1.jar` command to see what I mean.  Any additional suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: If you run `sbt clean publishLocal`, and then `jar -tf ~/.ivy2/local/com.github.mrpowers/spark-fast-tests_2.11/0.12.1/jars/spark-fast-tests_2.11.jar`, can you see the classes?

Comment: Yes, when I run those commands I can see the Scala classes in the JAR file.

Comment: Try bumping `addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype"  % "2.3")`, and then `sbt clean publish`. The `publish` command (instead of `release`) will publish a SNAPSHOT version to https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/mrpowers which enables us to test without polluting Maven production. See if the snapshot version has the same problem. `sbt-sonatype 2.3` has been cross built for SBT 0.13.17 which you are using: https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype/compare/xerial:706dba6...xerial:72f394c#diff-fdc3abdfd754eeb24090dbd90aeec2ceL32

Comment: When I run `sbt publish`, the snapshot JAR is uploaded here and includes the Scala classes: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/mrpowers/spark-fast-tests_2.11/  Unfortunately, when I run `sbt release`, the JAR files that are uploaded here https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspark-fast-tests_2.11 still don't include any of the Scala classes.

Comment: Can you login to https://oss.sonatype.org/#stagingRepositories and check if anything looks strange. Drop all stages and try again.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I had the same problem with `spark-testing-base`.
It stems from the way you modify the `artifactName`:

```scala
artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
  artifact.name + "-" + module.revision + "." + artifact.extension
}
```

which is probably copied from the [official SBT docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Artifacts.html).
Note that the docs have the following hint below the code though:

> (Note that in practice you rarely want to drop the classifier.)

My solution for `spark-testing-base` is the following:

```scala
  artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
    Artifact.artifactName(sv, module, artifact).replaceAll(s"-${module.revision}", s"-${sparkVersion.value}${module.revision}")
  }
```

This should make sure to keep the classifier (and whatever additional things might go into the `artifactName`) and solved the problem of JAR files containing documentation instead of class files.